# Samsung Galaxy S3 is not detected in Eclipse, but is visible in command line ADB

Tags: android, eclipse

The first strange thing is that months ago my Samsung Galaxy S3 was visible in Eclipse, but now it isn't. I have updated Eclipse, ADT and driver software for my device. In the device manager I can see SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface, but not USB Composite Device, which I don't know whether it's a problem or not.

When I try to find my device using command line and typing `adb devices` my device is shown, 
but I get this:
`List of devices attached`
`4df1e428290b4f91    device`
And my "normal" name for my device is GT-I9300. Has this anything to do with my problem?

I have turned on developer mode on my device.

Hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried out Kies and kill-server, start-server.
I also get the error "Running Android Lint" has encountered a problem, which is because of java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Install Samsung Kies software - http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Comment: restart ur adb and eclipse and check. Before that kill "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server"

Comment: Aerrow and Harsha, I have done the following things, 
and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I think there were another two checkbox option that goes something like "Allow unsigned applications to run on this device" and "Allow applications to debug on this device". Don't remember the exact names, but try enabling them

Comment: Neither did that work. I simply don't get it. And it hasn't anything to do with the version of Eclipse (4.2.1.v20130118) and ADT (23.0.2)?

Comment: And suddently it worked. Maybe it was my own fault because I just tried to click on run and something strange appeared, and now it is running on my phone. Thanks for the comments, but I will give Arnab the "points" for it. How can I make your, Arnab, comment to the answer?

Comment: And suddently Eclipse could find my device!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
I did everything as I wrote, and did the things people suggested in comments.

I restarted my computer, and then it worked.

Sorry for my late answer.